# Sum of two columns in mysql

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I am working in a crystal report and I am generating performance based report. This is my query

```
select mguser.userID, mguser.userName as Loger,date_format(trschedule.insDate,'%Y-%m-%d') as _Date,
count(distinct trschedule.scheduleID) as Schedule_Count, count(*) segment_count
FROM
mguser
```

I want summation of these two columns--- count(distinct trschedule.scheduleID) as Schedule_Count, count(*) segment_count

How can I do this in mysql???

Comment: Whats the result of above query.......?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Loger,_Date, (Schedule_Count + segment_count) sum from
(
  select mguser.userID, mguser.userName as Loger,
     date_format(trschedule.insDate,'%Y-%m-%d') as _Date,
     count(distinct trschedule.scheduleID) as Schedule_Count, 
      count(*) segment_count
  FROM
  mguser
)d
```